BigQuery Policy Tags: possible as infra as code?
Like other cloud providers, Google Cloud Platform handles data access rights with a mish-mash of mechanisms.
GCP supports tags, IAM permissions and roles, etc. But it also supports BigQuery policy tags.
"Normal" tags can be managed via infra as code. For instance, here it is for Terraform.
But I cannot find any way to manage BigQuery policy tags via infra as code. Is this possible?
I don't need infra as code, per se, but I need the core guarantees that it provides for this use case:

Free, up-to-date documentation ==> the repository (or some other centralized location) contains the truth on what policies are deployed, and how.
Occasional checks and guarantees that the real world matches our understanding.

terraform plan and apply check to ensure that what exists in the wild matches understanding of what should be in the wild.



How can I achieve this, with BigQuery policy tags?  Any examples or documentation would be greatly appreciated!

BigQuery terraform module supports natively to manage the tags now, using google_tags_tag_key, google_tags_tag_value, resource_tags
Reference:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tags#terraform
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_dataset#resource_tags-1


Yes, thanks!  I have switched over to use it.

Mike ... I'm not getting it.  In your original post, you discussed the TWO concepts of the English word "tags" ... one being "tags" and the other being "policy tags".  Our solution so far has been explicitly discussing "policy tags".  I am sensing the input from SANN3 relates to "tags" and not "policy tags".  Can you elaborate?

Here is a recipe that I use to create and apply policy tags to tables via Terraform:

Create Policy Tag

# https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#datacatalog.categoryFineGrainedReader

data "google_iam_policy" "unrestricted_finegrained_reader" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/datacatalog.categoryFineGrainedReader"
    members = [
      "allAuthenticatedUsers",
    ]
  }
}

resource "google_data_catalog_taxonomy" "basic_taxonomy" {
  display_name =  "my_taxonomy"
  description = "A collection of policy tags"
  region = "us"
}

resource "google_data_catalog_policy_tag" "date_policy" {
  taxonomy = google_data_catalog_taxonomy.basic_taxonomy.id
  display_name = "Date"
  description = "<Add Description>"
}

resource "google_data_catalog_policy_tag_iam_policy" "policy" {
  policy_tag = google_data_catalog_policy_tag.date_policy.name
  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.unrestricted_finegrained_reader.policy_data
}


Create a dataset

# https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_dataset
# Let's create a dataset
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "tf_dataset" {
    dataset_id = "tf_dataset"
    description = "Test dataset for Terraform"
    friendly_name = "tf_dataset"
    location = "us"
}


Create a table

# https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_table
# Let's create a table!

resource "google_bigquery_table" "table1" {
  dataset_id  = google_bigquery_dataset.tf_dataset.dataset_id
  table_id    = "table1"
  description = "Sample table"
  schema      = <<EOF
    [
  {
    "name": "col1",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "col1",
    "policyTags":{
        "names": [
          "${google_data_catalog_policy_tag.date_policy.id}"
          ]
      }
  },
  {
    "name": "col2",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "col2"
  }
]
    EOF
}



Thanks, @Kolban .  I put the taxonomy in place and your answer was super-helpful!  I'm setting a bounty to reward your answer since normally answering this type of esoteric, rare question doesn't get much of a reward. :)

For others who might see this, here is a great resource that I couldn't seem to find at first within TF:  https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/data_catalog_policy_tag

Now @SANN3 has the right solution, because TF now supports natively managing the tags.
